# How can I keep certain variables in stargazer output using the keep argument

Tags: r, glm, stargazer

I have run a country and year fixed-effects logit regression by creating dummy variables and using the glm function. Given the year and time dummies, my output table is very long.
I tried to use the "keep" argument in the stargazer function to be able to report only certain variables in my regression output. However, for some reason, it does not work. Any lead would be appreciated. My code is below:

```
glm_model <- glm(undervalued ~ factor(ID) + factor(year) -1 + lag(agr_GDP) +lag(manu_GDP) + lag(intcapimp_X) + lag(Foreign_liab), data=paneldata_m5, binomial(link = "logit"))

stargazer(glm_model, type = "text", 
          dep.var.labels = "undervalued",  title="",  
          font.size="small", keep="lag(agr_GDP)")

I have also tried the following: 
stargazer(glm_model, type = "text", 
          dep.var.labels = "undervalued",  title="",  
          font.size="small", keep=c("lag(agr_GDP)", "lag(manu_GDP)")
```

When I run this, the output table does not show any of the explanatory variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked.

```
stargazer(glm_model, type = "text",
          dep.var.labels = "undervalued",  title="",  
          font.size="small", keep=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I have specified the variables I want to keep as a numeric vector.